# WHERE clause with INNER JOIN and Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have achieved my desired query but I want to know how this one worked. I have multiple tables on my database and my requirements was to take the `id` from table called **product** and using this `id`, I want to retrieve some data from multiple tables and **product id** is a `foreign key` to the other tables. The query below works fine (by the way I was just experimenting and luckily got this query).

```
SELECT ponsfdp.*, product.pName, product.pImage, product.productSizes FROM product
INNER JOIN priceOnSizesForDigitalPrinting AS ponsfdp ON ponsfdp.pId_fk = 
(SELECT pId FROM product WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%")
WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%";
```

[image: desired query]

But when I tried this query,

```
SELECT ponsfdp.*, product.pName, product.pImage, product.productSizes FROM product
INNER JOIN priceOnSizesForDigitalPrinting AS ponsfdp ON ponsfdp.pId_fk = 
(SELECT pId FROM product WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%");
```

[image: garbage query]
It contains all the data even with null fields too. Can someone explain to me how it works? My personal opinion is both query should return same data because on the second query, I am using a **subquery** and it returns only one `id`, on the other hand, first query has a **WHERE** clause which generates the same `id` but by the help of name. How does the first query returns very specific columns and second return all columns even null columns too? I need an explanation for both queries.

Comment: _(SELECT pId FROM product WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%")_ this query will give same output every time (i.e. pId =1 ) whiling matching for inner join condition with all records. And in first query, you have applied additional filter of WHERE on result set. Hence you are getting only one record.

Comment: A better way to write the query is `SELECT ponsfdp.*, product.pName, product.pImage, product.productSizes FROM product
INNER JOIN priceOnSizesForDigitalPrinting AS ponsfdp ON ponsfdp.pId_fk = 
product.pid
WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%";` The subquery is unnecessary and confuses the issue (which is that your second query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause)

Comment: @SureshGajera basically where clause is condition for first part result set ?

Comment: @haider That is correct but WHERE condition will apply only after INNER join execution.

Comment: @Nick which query is faster ? yours or mine ? i am very new that is why i am asking

Comment: @haider it would depend on the query optimiser. In theory they can be optimised to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query also returning all rows as returned from your second query. But, when you are adding the last filter-

```
WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%"
```

It's just keeping one single row from all rows where pName is like 'booklet'. You can consider the output from your second query as a single table and your logic working as  below-

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ponsfdp.*, product.pName, product.pImage, product.productSizes 
    FROM product
    INNER JOIN priceOnSizesForDigitalPrinting AS ponsfdp 
    ON ponsfdp.pId_fk = (SELECT pId FROM product WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%")
)A
WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%"
```

Hope this will at least give you some insight of your query.

Comment: that is best explanation thank you just a quick question what A after parenthesis ?

Comment: A is the the is Alias for the returned data set from the Sub Query. This becomes the table name for the output and the outer query then consider A as a table.

Comment: You can use any other Alias name as you want. I used "A" just for example here :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for a subquery here.  You should be using the where condition to select rows from your FROM table, then use the ON clause of your join to find the right record(s) in your joined table for *each row* of the FROM table:

```
SELECT ponsfdp.*, product.pName, product.pImage, product.productSizes
FROM product
INNER JOIN priceOnSizesForDigitalPrinting AS ponsfdp
    ON ponsfdp.pId_fk = pId
WHERE pName LIKE "%booklet%";
```